# C++ boost::bind/lambda and operator bool()

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, bind

How do I bind a conversion-to-bool operator using boost::bind or boost::lambda?

For example, suppose I have a class C, with an operator bool(), and a `list<C>`. How do I use remove_if and bind/lambda to remove all elements that, when converted to bool, evaluate to false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `std::bind` or `std::remove_if` for this; `std::remove` will suffice:

```
std::vector<T> v; // Assuming T provides some conversion to bool

// Remove all elements that evaluate to 'false':
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), false), v.end());
```

Or, you can use the `std::logical_not` function object with `std::remove_if`:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::logical_not<T>()), v.end());
```

It is very rare that a class should implement an actual `operator bool()` overload:  due to problems with the C++ type system, providing such a conversion makes it very easy to mistakenly write incorrect code that makes use of the conversion where you don't expect it to be used.  It is far better to implement the safe-bool idiom instead of an actual `operator bool()` overload.  The downside of this is that you can't actually bind to the `operator bool()` overload since the safe-bool idiom relies on a conversion to some unspecified type.

Comment: Note that there are differences between the `remove` approach and the `remove_if` approach:  the `remove` approach relies on the use of `operator==` and won't work for types that are explicitly not equality comparable.  For instance, the `remove` approach will not work for a range of `std::function` objects but the `remove_if` approach, which relies only on the use of `operator!`, will work just fine.  [I'll edit this into my answer at some point.]

Comment: Thanks. You're right that in this case remove (instead of remove_if) is the easiest approach. Using logical_not also works; it would be even nicer if T were somehow automatically deduced by the compiler, but well.

Comment: @imre:  In this case it's pretty easy to write your own function object that doesn't require a template argument:  `struct awesome_not { template <typename T> bool operator()(const T& x) { return !x; } };` [I'll also edit that into my answer eventually.]

Answer (score 0):

use std::logical_not if you need to remove if the operator evaluates to false; if you need to remove if true, then you can use:

```
remove_if(..., ..., bind(&C::operator bool, _1));
```